# How to send a variable inside a loader.render_to_string to display it in html

Tags: python, django

I have a function that sends email and I want to send a variable to be displayed in the HTML email template file:
My django view:

```
     id=2
     html = loader.render_to_string(template,id)

     part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
     msg.attach(part2)
```

Comment: Did you search the documentation before posting this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) accepts `context` as the second parameter. Use it like:

```
html = loader.render_to_string(template, {'id': id})
```

Comment: how to display it inside html?

Comment: Just like a variable in a regular template: `{{ id }}`